# Count occurences of word in all files seperately in directory

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I am having *.txt files in a directory,where I want to search occurence of '>' in each *.txt file.I am trying the following command :

```
grep '>' *.txt|wc -l
```

But it is giving me a total sum of all occurrences in the directory and not one file at a time.

Comment: Do you want to count a line like `==>>> Example` as three occurances or as one (one line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wc` is useless, use the -c parameter of grep (man grep):

```
grep -c '>' *.txt
```

Comment: What if the file has >>> continuously? just curious.

Comment: @VigneshSP: I suppose the same since @shome used the `-l` parameter of `wc` (that means he wants the number of lines and not the number of occurrences, but I can be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Using awk. First some test data:

```
$ cat f1
> a > b
> c
$ cat f2
d e 
f
```

An awk script:

```
$ awk '
FNR==1 { f[FILENAME]=0 }  # define an array element for each file
(c=gsub(/>/,"&")) {       # count >s on record
    f[FILENAME]+=c
}
END {                     # in the end
    for(i in f)           # iterate all files
        print i,f[i]      # and output
}' f1 f2
```

Output:

```
f1 3
f2 0
```

Using `grep` you lose files without hits:

```
$ grep -Ho \> f1 f2 | cut -d : -f 1 | uniq -c
      3 f1
```